# Twitter Python API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Twitter API in Python to search users https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.search_users

```
API.search_users(q[, per_page][, page])
```

Parameters:

1. q – The query to run against people search.
2. per_page – Specifies the number of statuses to retrieve. May not be greater than 20.
3. page – Specifies the page of results to retrieve. Note: there are pagination limits.

But there is no documentation on how to create "q". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's in the regular twitter API docs, tweepy is just a wrapper: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators

Comment: `q` is just a string which is used for searching the users